# strtoll and division not returning correct numbers

Tags: c, math, precision

I have a problem with some built-in functions for C. Basically what I'm trying to create is my own colpitts oscillator calculator which takes the following inputs in order as arguments: Inductor value, Capacitor value, second capacitor value.

Inputs can end in F, or H and can also have a prefix p, m, n, and u to represent pico, milli, nano, and micro. The output will also be formatted if the number is too large and a suffix will be appended to it.

The problem I have with my program after inserting the debug printf statements is that the number conversion isn't correct.

I have used the test arguments as the following in this order:

```
1p 2pF 3F
```

This is my initial output:

```
DEBUG Init proc: 1p                     
DEBUG post proc: 0.000000               
DEBUG Init proc: 2p                     
DEBUG post proc: 0.000000               
DEBUG Init proc: 3                      
DEBUG post proc: 3.000000
```

But the DEBUG post proc lines are wrong except for the last.

I wanted to see:

```
DEBUG Init proc: 1p                     
DEBUG post proc: 0.000000000001               
DEBUG Init proc: 2p                     
DEBUG post proc: 0.000000000002               
DEBUG Init proc: 3                      
DEBUG post proc: 3.000000
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
  if (argc < 4){
printf("Need 3 args: L, C1, C2. %d supplied\n",argc-1);return -1;
  }
  long double nums[4],f;long isnum;
  int n=0;
  for (n=1;n<4;n++){
//process each arg
char *p=argv[n];while(*p != '\0'){p++;};p--;
//strip last character if it's F, f, H, or h
if (*p=='F' || *p=='f' || *p=='H' || *p=='h'){*p='\0';p--;}
printf("DEBUG Init proc: %s\n",argv[n]);
switch (*p){
  case '0': //do nothing if new last character is a number
  break;
  case 'p': //convert picounit to unit 
  *p='\0';
  nums[n]=strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10)/1000000000000ULL;
  break;
  case 'n': //convert nanounit to unit 
  *p='\0';
  nums[n]=strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10)/1000000000ULL;
  break;
  case 'u'://convert microunit to unit 
  *p='\0';
  nums[n]=strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10)/1000000ULL;
  break;
  case 'm'://convert milliunit to unit 
  *p='\0';
  nums[n]=strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10)/1000ULL;
  break;
  default: //do nothing if new last character is a number from 1 to 9 or print error if it isn't u,m,n or p.
  isnum=strtol(p,NULL,10);
  if (isnum < 1 || isnum > 9 || isnum=='\0'){
    printf("Number %d is in bad format. Use suffix of either: uH mH nH pH uF mF nF pF\n",n);
    return -1;
  }
  nums[n]=strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10);
}
printf("DEBUG post proc: %Lf\n",nums[n]);
  }
  printf("Input values: %Lf,%Lf,%Lf\n",nums[1],nums[2],nums[3]);
  //calculate frequency
  f=1/(2*3.14159)*sqrt(nums[1]*((nums[2]*nums[3])/(nums[2]+nums[3])));
  char suf=' '; //prepare suffix to display frequency in user friendly format
  if (f > 1000000){f=f/1000000;suf='M';} //convert to Mhz if f > 1000000
  if (suf=='\0' && f > 1000){f=f/1000;suf='K';}
  printf("Frequency = %Lf %c hz\n",f,suf);
  return 0;
}
```

As I only have a 32-bit processor to work with, I feel my answers to this are limited. What can I do to correct this issue?

Comment: You're doing integer division, hence the result of e.g. `strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10)/1000000000000ULL` is (likely) 0 (an int); converting that to double, it will remain 0. Divide by 1000000000000.0 instead to force floating point division.

Comment: Ok, I added .0 to all the large numbers and it doesn't help.

Comment: Your code will access out of bounds if an argument of just `F` is given

Comment: I didn't think of that until you told me. Thanks for pointing that out. Luckily this program I'm making is for personal use otherwise I'd be in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

First - as mentioned by Evert - you are doing integer divisions. Writing `nums[n]=strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10)/(1000000000000.0);` or `nums[n]=((double)strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10))/1000000000000ULL` should solve this topic.

Once your numbers are correct, the output is probably rounded to the 6th decimal place:

> **C99 §7.19.6.1 The `fprintf` function**, `f`,`F`
>
> A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation in the style `[−]ddd.ddd`, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. **If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6;** ...

Write `printf("DEBUG post proc: %1.15Lf\n",nums[n])` and you should see the remainders.

Comment: In the case of such small numbers, using the `e` formatter is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Both `nums[n]=strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10)/(1000000000000.0); nor nums[n]=((double)strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10))/1000000000000ULL` have a short coming.  The quotient may be calculated using `double` math, yet the result is stored in a `long double`.  Suggest `nums[n] = strtoll(argv[n],NULL,10)/1.0e12L`;